# Postman not able to find method in controller

Tags: spring-boot, controller, get-request

I have a project on spring boot and I am having trouble doing a simple get request to my controllers.

This is what my controller class look like.

```
package com.team4.controllers;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/king")
public class KingController {
    
    @Autowired 
    private KingRepository kingRepo;
    
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<King> list() {
        return kingRepo.findAll();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public King get(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return kingRepo.getReferenceById(id);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public King create(@RequestBody final King king) {
        return kingRepo.saveAndFlush(king);
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/update")
    public King update(@RequestBody final King king) {
        return kingRepo.saveAndFlush(king);
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        kingRepo.deleteById(id);
    }

}
```

However a get request on postman http://localhost:8080/king/all is giving me
"timestamp": "2023-03-07T01:17:43.041+00:00",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "No message available",
"path": "/king/all"

This is what my main class look like

```
package com.team4;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan( basePackages = {"com.team4.model.*"} )
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.team4.model.*")
@ComponentScan( basePackages = { "com.team4.model.*", "com.team4.controllers.*" } )

public class BoardGameProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        SpringApplication.run(BoardGameProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

    
    
}
```

If I put a method in this class postman can access it. I am confused why it is not doing that for my controller. What should I do?

The only difference between these two classes is the package they are in.

Answer (score 0):

Spring cannot find your controller, because you forced it to search in a subpackage under com.team4.controllers, and not in a com.team4.controllers itself.
Change your component scan settings from

```
@ComponentScan( basePackages = { "com.team4.model.*", "com.team4.controllers.*" } )
```

to

```
@ComponentScan( basePackages = { "com.team4.model.*", "com.team4.controllers" } )
```

and probably even better would be

```
@ComponentScan( basePackages = { "com.team4" } )
```